# Parsing XML from ftp to program

Tags: android, xml, parsing, ftp

Greetings,
I'm trying to parse an XML I received from an FTP. I follow a couple of tutorials but they didn't work out so wel.. My code is now:

```
              URLConnection cn;
              URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
              cn = url.openConnection();
              cn.connect();
              InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
              DocumentBuilder docBuild = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
              Document trDoc = docBuild.parse(stream);

              NodeList nodes = trDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name");
```

Now I have to get the Name in a string and log this string for testing. Can someone help me please?

Edit:
When I do this:

```
         for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){

              String toe = nodes.item(i).toString();
              Log.d("toe?",""+toe);
             // Log.d("nodes:",""+nodes.item(i))
              /*
            if (nodes.item(i).getTextContent().compareTo(original) == 0){
             System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent() + " > " + newValue);
             nodes.item(i).setTextContent(newValue);
            }*/
          }
```

I get:

```
04-08 14:47:29.989: DEBUG/toe?(737): org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl@44c5d228
```

XML code is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Personnel>
  <Employee type="permanent">
        <Name>Seagull</Name>
        <Id>3674</Id>
        <Age>34</Age>
   </Employee>
  <Employee type="contract">
      <Name>Tom</Name>
</Personnel>
```

Regards

Comment: Can you post some sample XML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the latest tutorial on my blog: [p-xr.com](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/)
It comes with a full source Eclipse project

Hope it helps!

Edit:

Try changing:

```
NodeList nodes = trDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name");
```

To

```
NodeList nodes = trDoc.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
```

Comment: blijkbaar wilt hij XMLfunctions niet doen.. :)

Comment: Try downloading the eclipse project from my blog. I think it will help you. You can always leave a comment there aswell

Comment: Woeps, I was trying to edit, so I think I removed yours? I'm a noob here.. sry =) Can you do it again? =$

Comment: don't seem to get it running in my code. Should I search for "parmanent"? of "Name"? "Personnel"? Also, you use httpRequest, why is that?

Comment: Ok, I tried your source code, and now it works, only when I use your xml, and paste it in my ftp location (http://www.stylefever.be/external/xmlTest.xml) It says "geen resultaten gevonden". I guess this is because you use the httpPost? How can integrate this xml into http? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Thats no XML .. :-) thats a .doc thats renamed to .xml. try copy/pasting your xml into notepad and then save it as xmlTest.xml + uploading

Comment: Ok that worked in notepad.. I made it in textedit on my mac.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use sax parser... it can be like this:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

URL sourceUrl = new URL(xmlURL);
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

now you need to have a class of myXMLHandler extending form DefaultHandler like this:

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler 
{

    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;


    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes)
    throws SAXException 
    {
        currentElement = true;               
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
    throws SAXException 
    {
        currentElement = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
    throws SAXException 
    {
        if (currentElement) 
        {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }


    }

}
```

Now StartElement() will be automatically called when this class gets any starting element... characters function on getting any value....