# Parsing xml file from ftp not http

Tags: android, http, ftp, xml-parsing, joomla2.5

I'm building xml parser, and am using this method:

```
String xml = "";
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

which bring all xml file as string.

But when I uploaded the xml file to the host (which is web hosting for Joomla) i can't view it or access the xml using http:

http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile.xml

I can only access the xml file using ftp:

ftp://mywebsite.com/myfile.xml

How can I parse this xml file by accessing it from ftp, or how to allow accessing the files on Joomla website from http ?

Comment: @njzk2: i am sorry i don't get your question but am using DOM parser and i tried to parse it for testing, by uploading it to http://www.zymic.com/ host which i'd been able to parse it successfully but after i tried uploading the xml file to "my company" website files i cant open the file using http so my parsing method failed

Comment: so, have you, like, a lead on how to fetch an ftp file?

Comment: @njzk2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595159/parsing-xml-from-ftp-to-program

I tried this but it hadn't worked and i don't know where to put the ftp username and password can you help me with this

Comment: This is not a Joomla, Android or parsing issue. It's most likely a server issue. What is the default directory for your FTP? Is it the same as your http directory? What happens when you try to access the file via http? Do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: @BrentFriar (1) Yes its the same directory, (2) and the error is "The page you requested is NOT AVAILABLE, A general error has occurred" , (3) as i remember its IOExeption

Comment: Well, the next easy step would be to upload an XML file to the server and try to access it. If you get the same error, then the problem is server related. If not, then the problem is most likely the file you are creating. Have you looked at the contents of the file you created? You should validate the file to make sure there is nothing wrong with the file you are creating - http://www.xmlvalidation.com/